# How to give multiple node output for Elasticsearch in beats.yml configuration file?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, metricbeat

I have multiple nodes in my elasticsearch cluster. How can I route traffic to the multiple nodes in my metricbeat configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Elasticsearch Output in your metricbeat configuration file, you can give multiple node output in an array format like this,

```
hosts: ["https://IP_Node_01:9200","https://IP_Node_02:9200","https://IP_Node_03:9200"]
```

This gives failover capability, where beats can connect to other nodes in case of failed nodes.